# How to solve the confusion when using Mockito.any()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to mock the result of a method that is called two times with different params.

I used this code

```
Mockito.when(rt.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), Mockito.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), Mockito.<Class<String>> any())).thenReturn(response);

Mockito.when(rt.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), Mockito.<HttpEntity<?>>any(), Matchers.<Class<InfsEspecificasDTO>> any())).thenReturn(responseInfoEsp);
```

Howevere, when I launch the test the first Mock is always the one executed.
How to solve this confusion. I tried specifying the 4th param in the second Mock as `InfsEspecificasDTO.class` but I get

> InvalidUseOfMatchersException

How can I solve the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `doAnswer` solution. The first three params do not matter, you only chech the instance of the last one:

```
when(rt.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(), any()))
  .thenAnswer((invocation) -> {
     Object paramToCheck = invocation.getArguments()[3];

     if(paramToCheck instanceof String){
       return response;
     }else if (paramToCheck instanceof InfsEspecificasDTO){
       return responseInfoEsp;
     }

     return null;

  });
```